# How to make the label show up after I added details

Tags: swift

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
// iPhone 11 Pro Max - 1

var boo = UILabel()
boo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 896)
boo.backgroundColor = .white

boo.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1,blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
boo.layer.cornerRadius = 20
```

So i did this but I don’t know how to let it show up in the Preview
Can you help me?
I am totally beginner and i know nothing. I just copy and pasted:
[Screenshot of my Playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oayb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preview using `PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView()`. here is an example.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to display UIKit components you may do that like

```swift
var boo = UILabel()
boo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 414, height: 896)
boo.backgroundColor = .red

boo.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1,blue: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
boo.layer.cornerRadius = 20
boo.text = "foo"

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = boo
```